# Does Flash pro automatically adjust my game's resolution for all devices?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, resolution

I created my game using flash pro and i have been testing it with my smartphone and it's size is 480x800. So i set the document size in the FLA file as 480x800.

But I'm wondering if my app will automatically adjust its resolution to fit other sizes such 1280x720 and 960x640.

If not, how can I make it so that it automatically adjusts its resolution to fit the size of any smartphone as much as possible but without losing 480x800 ratio. So I would expect little bit of empty spaces on any side of the other smartphones. Or i guess i could make the background picture a little bit "extra" bigger than 480x800?

oh and my smartphone is LG Android

Answer (score 0):

No, you should do all yourself. Also you should design game so It will look ok on various screens.

```
//Startup of the game, initial settings for the stage, 
//and getting screen size
public function Main() {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
}

private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

    //Width and Height
    trace(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}
```

To fit background in any screen size:

```
private function fitBackground(background:Bitmap, screenWidth:uint, screenHeight:uint):void {
    var availableRatio:Number = screenWidth / screenHeight;
    var componentRatio:Number = background.width / background.height;
    if (componentRatio < availableRatio) {
        background.width = screenWidth;
        background.height = screenWidth / componentRatio
    } else {
        background.width = screenHeight * componentRatio;
        background.height = screenHeight;
    }

    background.x = (screenWidth - background.width) >> 1;
    background.y = (screenHeight - background.height) >> 1;
}

//Usage
fitBackground(myBackground, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight)
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply. I did the first codes and I think it worked great. Actually, I don't have other smartphones or tablets to test it on so I'm not sure. Is there a way to test it? like in a virtual tablet or something? or do I need to buy a tablet?

Comment: and I'm using Sprite for my background picture and my game is using 3 different backgrounds. so the function didn't work showing an error. so I changed the parameter type to: private function fitBackground(background:GameBgMyOwn, screenWidth:uint, screenHeight:uint):void {

Comment: because my background is declared as GameBgMyOwn which is a sprite. gameBg = new GameBgMyown();
addChild(gameBg);
   
fitBackground(gameBg, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight); // and then I called function here

Comment: But it gave me an error: 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: GameBgMyOwn.

Comment: Check, if all exports for ActionScript are correct. And if your background isn't `Bitmap` better `fitBackground(background:DisplayObject, screenWidth:uint, screenHeight:uint)`

Comment: the same error is occured so I moved the function's content to where I placed addChild(gameBg) and replaced 'background' with 'gameBg' but unfortunately all I see is blue background. But if I comment the function's content the game shows up correctly.

Comment: Sorry I didn't assign the variables with stagewidth. Now, the game screen shows up great except the left hand side of the background is cropped because actually the whole background is moved to left like 5 to 10 px.(my game's width is 480 px). Anyway to fix it? Thank you alot.